# set -e and bash file termination status

Tags: bash

I want to launch automated tests from a bash file and it's important that the bash file would exit with non-zero status if a test fails.

The issue is that I need to run an afterscript when the tests are done.

Ho do I do it with logical satements?

```
set -e 
python -m pytest
python ./afterscript.py
```

So, I need to run ./afterscript.py even if the pytest fails, yet in case of test failure, I need the file to be exited with an error status after the afterscript is run.

Comment: Why do you use `set -e` then?

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
set -e 
python -m pytest || true
python ./afterscript.py
```

That way, no matter what the exit status of `python -m pytest` is, the alternative is `true` and therefore `set -e` will not terminate your script.